# How to call javascript function from code-behind after ajax postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm using Telerik controls in my project and I am using RadTabStrip for my purposes

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="tsRequisitions" Skin="" MultiPageID="mpRequisitions" runat="server" Width="980"  ScrollButtonsPosition="Right" ScrollChildren="True" OnTabCreated="tabCreated">
```

As you can see in this template I call `tabCreated` method every time when new tab has created. Now I want to call some javascript function from server-side(all mentioned is in RadAjaxPanel).

I've tried to use `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, but it didn't help me to fire my javascript function.

```
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("tabSelected"))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
                    "tabSelected", "TabSelected();", true);
            }
```

And I have this in my  `.aspx` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TabSelected() {
       console.log("dfgdfgfdg");
    }          
</script>
```

How can I call my function from code-behind after AJAX postback?

Comment: have you tried `RegisterStartupScript` instead?

Comment: If you are rendering HTML, then you can try having the http post response render "<script>TabSelected();</script>".  When the browser renders the html it will execute the javascript method.

Comment: @ChuckNorris - What about `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet do the trick

```
RadScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "tabSelectedScript", "TabSelected();", true);
```

`RegisterStartupScript` is static method of `RadScriptManager` class (I'm using Telerik controls here again, but maybe it will work with asp.net standart ScriptManager too).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("OnLoad", "<script>TabSelected();</script>");
```